# what query should we use to split 1colmnn into multiple column

Tags: mysql

```
Table name-userdb
id |  name  |  value
1  | fname   | anand
1  | lname   | kumar
1  |city     | bangalore
2  |fname    |mahesh
2  |lname    |sahoo
2  |city     |manglore
3  |fname    |anil
3  |lname    |singh
3  |city     |balasore
```

i need to disply like

```
fname  |  lname  |  city
anand  |  kumar  | bangalore
mahesh | sahoo   | manglore
anil   |singh    |balasore
```

for this please give me the mysql query

Comment: Please give an example data showing how you as a human would work out which column the "value" would go into

Comment: column name- "Name","value".row1-fname,x,row2-lname,y,row3-city,z etc. and the result will come like column name-"fname","lname","city" etc.. row1-x,y,z row2-say p,q,r.. hope you will get what i am asking

Comment: Post us either the actual data or some test data, "Etc" "...." don't really go well with explaining something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [spliting of one column into several column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594076/spliting-of-one-column-into-several-column)

Comment: @richard-aka-cyberkiwi not just possible duplicate its EXACT duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

mmm.. EAVS...Beyond the obvious suggestions of actually implementing a design, you can achieve what you want like so:

```
Select Min( Case When name = 'fname' Then value End ) As fname
    , Min( Case When name = 'lname' Then value End ) As lname
    , Min( Case When name = 'city' Then value End ) As city
From MyTable
Group By Id
```