# spliting of one column into several column

Tags: mysql

```
Table name-userdb,
id |  name   |  value,
1  | fname   | anand,
1  | lname   | kumar,
1  |city     | bangalore,
2  |fname    |mahesh,
2  |lname    |sahoo,
2  |city     |manglore,
3  |fname    |anil,
3  |lname    |singh,
3  |city     |balasore..
```

i need to disply like

```
fname  |  lname  |  city,
anand  |  kumar  | bangalore,
mahesh | sahoo   | manglore,
anil   |singh    |balasore,
```

for this please give me the mysql query

Comment: You already asked this exact same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593708/what-query-should-we-use-to-split-1colmnn-into-multiple-column

Comment: yaa..but didnt get the answer..

Comment: It may take more than a few minutes to get an answer, if you explain your problem better you may have more luck. Just posting exactly the same question again is not likely to get any better response.

Comment: I'm confused, you have a table with three columns, `id`,`name` and `value`?

Comment: @pritosh Have you considered perhaps restructuring your table definition?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend restructuring your database, this is not a viable way of handling requests.

```
SELECT udb1.value as fname, udb2.value as lname, udb3.value as city
FROM `name-userdb` udb1
JOIN `name-userdb` udb2 ON udb1.id=udb2.id AND udb2.name='lname'
JOIN `name-userdb` udb3 ON udb1.id=udb3.id AND udb3.name='city'
WHERE udb1.name='fname';
```

Again! This is `not` the right way to do it!
I'm only putting the answer here because it looks similar to a tag/filter system and someone might need the answer.

Comment: You should consider saving this kind of data in multiple fields and doing one `select * FROM userdb WHERE id=1;` !

Comment: you can do it without the multi-way join using a max(case ...) construct and a group-by

Comment: @Simom "Add Another Answer" compels you!

Answer (score 0):

mmm.. EAVS...Beyond the obvious suggestions of actually implementing a normalized design, you can achieve what you want like so:

```
Select Min( Case When name = 'fname' Then value End ) As fname
    , Min( Case When name = 'lname' Then value End ) As lname
    , Min( Case When name = 'city' Then value End ) As city
From MyTable
Group By Id
```